# Upload de vários aquivos, porém, cada um por vez?

Tags: php, javascript, upload

Estou a procura de algum código que faça upload de vários arquivos para o servidor PHP, porém no estilo do Google Drive: Um arquivo por vez, mas no mesmo form.
Tipo a imagem abaixo:

[image: upload]

Comment: Voce nao precisa de um codigo para isso, e so ir fazendo o upload conforme o response do anterior, e sempre no final do response verificar se falta algum para enviar.

Comment: Eu ia colocar minha resposta de exemplo, mas tudo bem :/ https://pastebin.com/dHYRZ0GF

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DAR0Cyy4